# How to overload [] for a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I'm tasked with improving C arrays by implementing an array class with various functionality. I'm trying to overload '[]' but I've ran into an issue.

```
template<typename T>
class SA{
private:
  T* pT;
//other vars...

public: 
//other initialization functions...
int& operator [](int offset);
};

template<typename T>
int& SA<T>::operator [](int offset){
  if (offset < lIdx || offset > hIdx){
    std::cout << "invalid index:" << std::endl;
  }

  return pT[offset];
}

int main(){
  SA<float> thing1(15);
  thing1[5] = 5;
  return 0;
```

When I use this overloading function, I'm met with this error:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int&’ to an
> rvalue of type ‘int’

However, if I understand correctly I can't re-assign the value at this index with '=' if I remove the '&'. The compiler will also throw this error if I do so:

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Shouldn't the return type be `T&` instead of `int&`?

Comment: The array is of type `float`, but your `operator[]` is trying to return an `int&`

Comment: the problem is with the return type when you use this template class for ```const int``` value type. try adding another overload for that too

Comment: If the offset is not in range, throw an exception `std::out_of_range` rather than allowing the program to crash

Comment: @Wander3r: No, the crash makes perfect sense. The throwing variant ought to be named `at()`, just like `std::vector::at` and `std::array::at`. Array classes are pretty primitive building blocks, and adding unreachable exception code can there slow down a lot of code.

Comment: @MSalters This is a nice information to remember. Thank you for pointing this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of the function should be `T&`, not `int&`:

```
T& operator [](int offset);
```

Also note that, while it is nice that you check to make sure the index is in range, you don't actually do anything about it. One solution is to throw an exception:

```
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
T& SA<T>::operator[](int offset) {
  if (offset < lIdx || offset > hIdx)
    throw std::out_of_range{"Array index out of range"};
  return pT[offset];
}
```

If you really want to be consistent with STL containers, let `operator[]` be unchecked, and add a debug-time check like:

```
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
T& SA<T>::operator[](int offset) noexcept { // note noexcept
  assert(offset < lIdx || offset > hIdx);
  return pT[offset];
}
```

Adding a const-overload of this operator would also be nice:

```
const T& operator [](int offset) const noexcept;
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. The assertion was a really cool addition as well!

Answer (score 0):

first you should adjust the return type according to your value type:

```
template<typename T>
T& SA<T>::operator [](int offset){
  if (offset < lIdx || offset > hIdx){
    std::cout << "invalid index:" << std::endl;
  }

  return pT[offset];
}
```

Then if you want it to also work in constant mode add the following overload:

```
template<typename T>
const T& SA<T>::operator [](int offset)const{
  if (offset < lIdx || offset > hIdx){
    std::cout << "invalid index:" << std::endl;
  }

  return pT[offset];
}
```